# Decode MP4 video with VideoDecoder - avcC problem

Tags: javascript, webcodecs

I am trying to decode this video with WebCodecs in Google Chrome: https://www.photopea.com/test_video.mp4 . My code used to work in the past with this video, but it stopped to work with Chrome 115.

I am providing this configuration:

```
decoder.configure( {
    "codec": "avc1.640034",  // I use this for every AVC-encoded file
    "description": file.slice(577, 577+52)
} );
```

It prints the error

```
Failed to execute 'configure' on 'VideoDecoder': Failed to parse avcC.
```

Are you able to decode any frame of this file with VideoDecoder? How do you do it?

Comment: what even is `decoder`?

Comment: It is a usual WebCodecs terminology: var decoder = new VideoDecoder(...); My question is not about Javascript, but about a specific web API, and the format of video files.
https://developer.chrome.com/en/articles/webcodecs/

Comment: perhaps if you showed code that demonstrates your issue, then `decoder` wouldn't be just some random variable you believe everyone should just know :p

Comment: @IvanKuckir Does it work if you... **(1)** Set codec as: `"avc1.640028"` **(2)** Try slicing as: `file.slice(577, 577+44)`? That's the length of your AVC Config bytes (_ie:_ SPS & PPS). If still not working, let me now asap and I will test a possible solution.

Comment: @VC.One Cool! Could I use this configuration for all "avcC" files? The codec "avc1.640028" and the first 44 Bytes of the "vacC" chunk?

Comment: @IvanKuckir Did you get a picture displaying? Also to answer your other concern, no you cannot use same config. When I get a chance, I'll write an answer to detect the correct config from the input file's own bytes.